# Discord.py TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

guys so I'm working on a Filter that removes swear words. My problem is I'm getting a 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error. Could anyone explain why and how to fix it? I know that is error is costed by `getMutedValue = curs.fetchone()[0]` but if I would remove the [0] its wouldn't work.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    curs.execute('SELECT muted FROM user WHERE userID = (%s)', (message.author.id,))
    getMutedValue = curs.fetchone()[0]

    curs.execute('SELECT word FROM filter')
    getWord = curs.fetchone()

    curs.execute('SELECT immunity FROM user WHERE userID = (%s)', (message.author.id,))
    getImmunityValue = curs.fetchone()[0]

    if getMutedValue == 1:
        muted = message.author.mention + ' You are currently muted!'
        await message.channel.send(muted)
        await message.delete()

    if getImmunityValue == 0:
        for word in getWord:
            if getMutedValue == 0:
                if message.content.count(word) > 0:
                    channel = client.get_channel(729267888539828255)
                    id = message.author.id

                    curs.execute('SELECT username FROM user WHERE userID = (%s)', (id,))
                    getUsername = curs.fetchone()[0]

                    curs.execute(f'UPDATE user SET warning = +1 WHERE userID = {id}')
                    db.commit()

                    curs.execute('SELECT warning FROM user WHERE userID = (%s)', (id,))
                    getWarning = curs.fetchone()[0]

                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} Please do not use an swear words. If you continue you will get punished!')

                    Embed = discord.Embed(
                        title=f'{getWarning}x Warning from {getUsername}',
                        color=discord.Colour.red(),
                        timestamp=datetime.utcnow()
                    )

                    Embed.add_field(name='Blacklist Wort:', value=word, inline=False)
                    Embed.add_field(name='Channel-ID:', value=message.channel.id, inline=False)
                    Embed.add_field(name='Channel:', value=message.channel, inline=False)

                    await channel.send(embed=Embed)

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fetchone()` method can return None if there are no rows to fetch. ([Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html).) What the should the program do next? In the case where you're checking if a user is muted, the most sensible thing is probably to assume that they aren't muted.

For example:

```
row = curs.fetchone()
if row is not None:
    getMutedValue = row[0]
else:
    getMutedValue = 0
```

In the case where you get `None` back, you have a fallback value, 0. If you get a value back, then you use that value.