# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable even though checking the var with an if condition and setting it to a static value otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, python-requests

I am trying to write a prototype for web scraping. My problem is that I get the error in the title when `duetpartner = track['duet']['handle']`  is null or of NoneType.

The thing is I already made a check for it and I set it to a static value if it is None:

```
def create_song_list(track):
   if track['duet']['handle'] is not None:
       duetpartner = track['duet']['handle']
    else:
       duetpartner= 'Solo'

return {
        'Duet_partner': duetpartner
    }
```

I call `create_song_list` from within a array.

If more code is required to reproduce I shall supply it, I try to keep it minimal.

The simple solution got expired from a similar question, but still it's of NoneType for me...: [Discord.py TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944825/discord-py-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable)

## UPDATE 1:

Adding `or track['duet']` condition doesn't help...

Comment: It is likely that *track['duet'] is None*

Comment: @Fred yes, it can be None in some cases, hence the check. What's wrong with the check?

Comment: If track['duet'] is None then you can't subscript it

Comment: @Fred ok, I added a `or track['duet']` condition, yet still I get the same error...

Comment: Adding the *or* **after** the original test won't help as the expression will be evaluated left-to-right

Comment: @Fred replacing the order didn't help apparently..

Comment: @SirMuffington Do you actually mean it can take None as a value, or did you mean it can be a non-existant or missing dict/dict key? Because in the latter case, a good old try/except KeyError would work.

Comment: @Guimoute the logic is following: if the key's value value exists -> take it, otherwise - it's equal to Solo. Simple as that

Comment: @SirMuffington Yes but you understand the massive difference between existing and taking none as a value, existing and having a valid value, and not existing. If none is never a value, the two latter points can be handled nicely with a try/except KeyError. If none can be a value, it's more checks.

Comment: @Guimoute no, the key is `null` in the other case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you to understand what's going on. Let's have 3 dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'foo': 'banana'}
d2 = {'duet': {'foo': 'banana'}}
d3 = {'duet': {'handle': 'banana'}}
```

Now we're going to find out if a dictionary has a 'duet' key **and** if its value (which we assume is another dictionary) has a 'handle' key:

```
for d in d1, d2, d3:
    print(d.get('duet', dict()).get('handle'))
```

This gives:

```
None
None
banana
```

...which, hopefully, make sense.

This means that the function in the original question can be changed thus:

```
def create_song_list(track):
    v = track.get('duet', {'handle': 'Solo'}).get('handle', 'Solo')
    return {'Duet_partner': v}
```

Of course, this will only work if *track* is a dictionary **and** the value associated with *duet* is also a dictionary.

Therefore, an extremely robust approach could be:

```
def create_song_list(track):
    if isinstance(track, dict):
        if (duet := track.get('duet')) is not None:
            if isinstance(duet, dict):
                if (handle := duet.get('handle')) is not None:
                    return {'Duet_partner': handle}

    return {'Duet_partner': 'Solo'}
```

Comment: Does this have any performance benefits compared to Rajkumar's answer?

Comment: @SirMuffington The other answer is wrong although you seem to have accepted it as being correct

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code something like -

```
def create_song_list(track):
   if track['duet'] is not None and track['duet']['handle'] is not None:
       duetpartner = track['duet']['handle']
    else:
       duetpartner= 'Solo'

return {
        'Duet_partner': duetpartner
    }
```

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid. It was that simple.

Comment: This answer is flawed. If the dictionary passed to the function does not have a 'duet' key then KeyError will be raised